# CUPS printers are not selectable in the graphical interface

Tags: linux, printer, redhat-enterprise-linux, cups

My Linux (RHEL8) has a strange problem with the printers: I have printers installed on CUPS, but they are not displayed in the programs on the graphical interface!

When I try to print from a text editor or a browser, the only printer available is the "Save PDF" option. However, when I open `http://localhost:631`, the printers are there. I can even print test pages successfully.

I thought it was a desktop environment problem (I'm using Xfce4). However I logged in using Gnome, and the behavior is the same. Any ideas?